# Is there a way to use Regex to capture numbers out of a string based on a specific leading letters?

Tags: regex

I need to extract any number between 4-10 digits that following directly after 'PO#' OR 'PO# ' (with a whitespace). I do not want to include the PO# with the actual value that is extracted, however I do need it as criteria to target the value within a string. If the digits are less than 4 or greater than 10, I do not wish to capture the value and would like to otherwise ignore it.

A sample string would look like this:

PO#12445 for Vendor Enterprise

or

Invoice# 21412556 for Vendor Enterprise for PO# 12445

My current RegEX expression captures PO# with '#' and I use additional logic after the fact to remove the '#', however my expression is also capturing Invoice# and Inv# which I don't want it to do. I'd like it to only target PO#.

Current Expression: [P][O][#]\s*[0-9]{3,9}\d+\w

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: "I do not want to include the PO# with the actual value that is extracted, however I do need it as criteria to target the value within a string" => You need to capture 'PO#' or not? Only the digits?

Comment: Use lookbehind assertion. `(?<=PO#\s)\d{4,10}|(?<=PO#)\d{4,10}`. Since it as to be of fixed width, you'll have to repeat yourself. If an optional space before the captured number is OK, simplify the regex to `(?<=PO#)\s*\d{4,10}`.

Comment: @MaxXapi correct, I only needed the digits, which after you included Alexander's feedback, it worked like a charm. Thank you both so much!!! Also made me realize how much I have left to learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need only the digits, you can use `\b(?<=PO#)\s?(\d{4,10})\b`, with:

- `(?<=PO#)`: positivive lookbehind, be sure that this pattern is present before the needed pattern (PO followed by #)
- `\s?`: 0 or 1 whitespace
- `(\d{4,10})`: between 4 and 10 digits
- `\b`: word boundaries to avoid ie. the 10 first digits of a 11 digits pattern match or 'SPO#' to match

Edit: Alexander Mashin is right about the lookbehind having to be fixed width, so `\b(?<=PO#)\s?(\d{4,10})\b` is better https://regex101.com/r/1KBQd1/5

Edit: added word boundaries

Comment: This worked perfectly with the correction. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a capturing group and repeat matching the digits 4-10 times using `[0-9]{4,10}`.

Note that `[P][O][#]` is the same as PO#

```
\bPO#\s*([0-9]{4,10})\b
```

- `\bPO#\s*` Match PO# preceded by a word boundary and match 0+ whitespace chars
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `[0-9]{4,10}` Match 4 - 10 digits
- `)\b` Close group followed by a word boundary to prevent the match being part of a larger word

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1TWExn/1)

Answer (score 0):

If `PCRE` is available, how about:
`PO#\s*\K\d{4,10}(?=\D|$)`

- `PO#\s*` matches the leading substring "PO#" followed by  0 or more whitespaces.
- `\K` resets the starting position of the match and works as a positive (zero length) lookbehind.
- `\d{4,10}` matches a sequence of digits of 4 <= length <= 10.
- `(?=\D|$)` is the positive lookahead to match a non-digit character or the end of the string.